# Change Permission on ASP.NET folder after Publishing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, permissions, publish

I have a folder in my website which I need to make world readable after publishing it to my web server. Unfortunately just changing the permissions on the folder is no good as when I publish again it gets deleted as part of the publish process ad thus the permissions are reset to the permissions of the parent directory.

Is there an easy way to set these post deployment permissions or what is the equivalent of a post build step for the publish action. I get very few useful results if I search for post publish step.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking folder NTFS (ACL) permissions here rather than web security permissions (I think), the answer is complicated.  You have to add a custom target to Visual Studio's web publishing pipeline.  I can't detail it better than Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi does [here](http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/settingfolderpermissionsonwebpublish.aspx).